# How determine from client side if Google Play Billing subscription is expired

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I have implemented Subscriptions in mine Android app, and wondering how to check expired subscription. As I understood, expired subscription should not be returned in `getPurchases()` method.

The problem is - I tested 1 month subscription using test account (which renews subscription every 5 minutes, as described here https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions), and after expiration time I still recieved that purchase in `getPurchases()`, even after 1 day. However, if I manually tried to subscribe one more time, Play Market didn`t refuse, and everything worked fine.
Also, when I was selecting 'decline payment' in subscription settings, it dissapeared from purchases list, as it supposed to be.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -3):

I didn't understand what do you mean by "renews every 5 minutes".
Once you subscribe to Google play to any app/service, it will be available until the end of the subscription.

For example:
I purchased a subscription with an APP for 6 months.
I went to Google Play after 2 days and canceled my subscription but the app will still see that I am subscribed for the remaining 6 months because I already paid the subscription fees.

It's not something that you can handle from Google Play :)

Hope this helps.

Comment: I mean 'testing subscriptions renewal' https://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_testing#testing-subscriptions